# GeoCoordinateWatcher() in real windows phone device?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For getting Latitude and Longitude i wrote the following line of code.

```
watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
 var myPosition = myWatcher.Position;

     if (!myPosition.Location.IsUnknown)
          {
                latitude = myPosition.Location.Latitude;
                longitude = myPosition.Location.Longitude;
            }
```

But i am getting all values as **NAN** .Please tell me how to get current latitude and longitude in real device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the watcher?
Also you can simulate the GPS on emulator. There's a tool for that.

```
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.Start();

        GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

        if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}",
                coord.Latitude,
                coord.Longitude);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
        }
```