# how to get latitude and longitude of current location using c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c#,i have try to get the current location's latitude and longitude.  below is my code what i have tried.

**Code**

```
public string GetLocationProperty()
{
    double a = 0.0;
    string b = "";
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

    // Do not suppress prompt, and wait 1000 milliseconds to start.
    watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

    if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}",
        //    coord.Latitude,
        //    coord.Longitude);
        a = coord.Latitude;
        b = a.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting latitude value in `a` ?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: As a general rule, if you encounter a method called `TryXXX` it will tend to have a return value that indicates whether it was successful. And, indeed, [`TryStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.trystart(v=vs.110).aspx) does. So don't *ignore* that return value.

Comment: i try to get the lattitude value in a.but it return null

Comment: possible duplicate of [GeoCoordinateWatcher() in real windows phone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373695/geocoordinatewatcher-in-real-windows-phone-device)

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, accoding to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), latitude and logitude are accessible as properties of `GeoCoordinate`.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher= new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
watcher.Start(); //started watcher
GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
if (!watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
{
    double lat = coord.Latitude; //latitude
    double long = coord.Longitude;  //logitude
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get the current user location

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        watcher.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var coordinate = e.Position.Location;
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}", coordinate.Latitude, coordinate.Longitude);
            // Uncomment to get only one event.
            watcher.Stop();
        };

        // Begin listening for location updates.
        watcher.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher _geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
_geoWatcher.PositionChanged += GeoWatcher_PositionChanged;

bool isStarted = _geoWatcher.TryStart(suppressPermissionPrompt, timeOut);
_currentLocation = (isStarted && !_geoWatcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown) ? _geoWatcher.Position.Location: new GeoCoordinate();

private void GeoWatcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    _currentLocation = e.Position.Location;
    _geoWatcher.Stop();
}
```