# GeoCoordinate location is always unknown how can I fix this?

Tags: c#, geolocation

I'm trying to get the location of the user using the `System.Device.Location` but every time I run the program GeoCoordinate's IsUnknown property is always true. I'm not sure why it's always unknown I've turned on my system as well. Please help me fix this issue.

Here's what I tried so far.

```
static void GetLocationProperty()
        {
            CivicAddress civic = new CivicAddress();
            GeoCoordinate watcher = new GeoCoordinate();

            if (watcher.IsUnknown != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}, region:{2}", watcher.Latitude, watcher.Longitude, civic.CountryRegion);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
            }
        }
```

It always gives `watcher.IsUnknown` is true. Am I doing something wrong here or is it some permission access issue?

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Visual Studio 2017.

I have also tried this code from the MSDN website

```
using System;
using System.Device.Location;

namespace GetLocationProperty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetLocationProperty();
        }

        static void GetLocationProperty()
        {
            GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

            // Do not suppress prompt, and wait 1000 milliseconds to start.
            watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

            GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

            if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}",
                    coord.Latitude,
                    coord.Longitude);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GeoCoordinateWatcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try starting the watcher

Comment: ```watcher``` doesn't seem to have anything called "start" or "TryStart".

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [geoCoordinate default constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#system-device-location-geocoordinate-ctor) documentation you can see.

> Initializes a new instance of GeoCoordinate that has no data fields set.

I.e. a GeoCoordinate is a kind of data transfer object, it only represents a coordinate, not a way to generate such a coordinate from GPS or other sources. For that you probably want [GeoCoordinateWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher?view=netframework-4.8). See [How to get Latitude and Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297247/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-of-current-location-using-c-sharp)

Comment: when I use ```GeoCoordinateWatcher``` it gives me the "no such namespace exists" error.

Comment: @Skittari `GeoCoordinateWatcher` is not a namespace, so the compiler is correct in that regard. Check that you are using it correctly, i.e. `new GeoCoordinateWatcher();`

Comment: I copied and pasted the program from the MSDN website [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
and it still gives the error ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'GeoCoordinateWatcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: @Skittari note that the `System.Device.Location` classes only seem to be available in .Net framework. For .net Core/5/6/7 you need a nuget package, and possibly use different namespaces etc.

Comment: But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) says it applies to .NET versions 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8.

Comment: @Skittari ".net framework" is shorthand for versions 1-4.8. Later versions are named ".Net core" or just ".Net"

Comment: But even if you are using .Net framework you might need to add a reference to the `System.Devices` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to get the Localization from dvice you need to use the real watcher (**GeoCoordinateWatcher**):

**EDIT:** as seems that OP system is having some trouble locating the correct GeoCoordinateWatcher I propose explicit route

remember using:

```
using System;
using System.Device.Location;
```

And use this code instead:

```
    static void GetLocationProperty()
    {
        System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        // Do not suppress prompt, and wait 1000 milliseconds to start.
        watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;

        if (coord.IsUnknown != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}, Long: {1}",
                coord.Latitude,
                coord.Longitude);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the error i get when I run the code  ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'GeoCoordinateWatcher' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```

Comment: did you include the  using System.Device.Location;

Comment: yes, I even used the NuGet package manager to install it.

Comment: What version of framework are you using? Ups, I saw your edit, 4.6.1 must have the GeoCoordinateWatcher (it's there since 4.0) try unistaling the nuget package, perhaps there is some conflict

Comment: Try with the edited explicit route

Comment: Alright, I tried it out and I'm still getting the same error.